# Change color of individual List<T> items

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to have the font color of an item change when triggered and cannot for the life of me figure out the syntax to get the individual items the change. My code:

C#:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Mode { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
}

List<Person> personObjects = new List<Person>();

personObjects.Add(new Person()
{
    Name = testVariable,
    Mode = "Test",
    Time = testString1,
});

PersonListView.ItemsSource = personObjects;
```

XAML:

```xml
<ListView x:Name="PersonListView" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Height="258"
          Margin="5,268,0,0"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Width="165" 
          FontSize="10"
          ButtonBase.Click="GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler" >
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="16" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Person" 
                            Width="94"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Time" 
                            Width="44"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Time}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I've tried using `ListViewItem` properties but no luck

I've tried:

```
foreach (Person item in onCallListView.Items)
{
    if(trigger)
    {
       item.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
    }
}
```

The closest i've gotten is changing it in the XAML:

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
</Style>
```

**but it changes all of them items in the list, how can i change the items individually?**

I have a label that changes color pretty straight forward:

```
int secondsInMode = Convert.ToInt32(pullsDataFromString);
if (secondsInMode > 15 * 60)
   {
    personStatusLabel.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
   }
```

Could i use a boolean like:

```
public bool RED = false;
if (secondsInMode > 15 * 60)
   {
    RED = true;
   }
```

and have the DataTrigger triggered by the boolean?

Comment: The XAML will be more helpful than the C#

Comment: What do you intend to use as the trigger?

Comment: You could add a `Color` property in your Model class and Bind it to `ListViewItem`. But, Color property in `Person` class sounds strange. You could otherwise have some other property in you Model for binding and use `IValueConverter` to convert it to `Color`.

Comment: Ditto on the IValueConverter on some property of Person. If you want it to change dynamically you'll need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on Person too. Or similar

Comment: Sorry all, to be more clear, I am not having issues with the trigger itself, rather getting the individual items to change color when triggered.

Comment: But we have a problem with `trigger`, it only suggests a local variable. We'd like to see it as a property in your (View)Model class.

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger it as so:

```xml
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="16" />
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Time}" Value="456">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style>
```

If your `trigger` is more than just `some_property == some_value`, then you'll either need to create your own `ValueConverter` (see edit below)

If the property you're binding too can change dynamically, you'll also need to implement `PropertyChanged` on your property - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx

Good luck! Any questions, just ask.

### ADDITION - How to make a Converter:

If you need a more complicated trigger, you can do it like this:

C#:

```
public class TimeStringToIsLateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Do the conversion from your Time (ie value) to your "should the text be red" bool
        return ((string)value) == "456";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Not needed!
        return null;
    }
}
```

XAML:

Add your local namespace at the top, eg:

```xml
<Window ...
    xmlns:l="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
    ... />
```

Then have something as, eg:

```
    <ListView ...>
        <ListView.Resources>
            <l:TimeStringToIsLateConverter x:Key="TimeColourConverter" />
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="16" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Time, Converter={StaticResource TimeColourConverter}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.View>
        ...
```

Comment: I want the Trigger to be set when Time equals a certain value. Although the trigger is less of the question, I can't figure out how to get individual names to change color instead of the enter style on the ListView

Comment: So Time is changing? And you want it to change colour when it gets above a certain value?

You'll want the `DataTemplate` solution then... Can you give the code for what your trigger will actually be by any chance? :). Also, are you saving `Time` as a `string`? Not a `DateTime`? Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Okay, the code above works for me in the sense that it changes to red... when the `Time` is `456`. Until I know more about the trigger, it's hard to create a converter for you I'm afraid!

Comment: i need the entire line/object to change to red, but not all of them. Here's a screenshot if it helps. [link](http://oi59.tinypic.com/2dth5k.jpg)

Comment: Okay, then we want to change the Background then? (as per above?)

Comment: haha no sorry the background just happens to be red. I want the text to change color

Comment: So this is what you're after style-wise, right?: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25947597/ListViewScreenshot2.jpg

Comment: Okay, I need to head now. I'm still not 100% sure of your requirements, but the above works for me as I believe you want it. If your Time changes dynamically, you may need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` as per the links I mention above. I would also recommend changing the `Time` to be a `DateTime`, or `TimeSpan` and using another converter to convert the `DateTime` or `TimeSpan` to a string on the binding...
Anyway, good luck!

Comment: yes your picture is correct, however can i just trigger the color change with a boolean? for example please see update above

Comment: Yes - but it will need to be a property (not a field), and will need to be on the `Person` class - the standard way to implement it would be a pure `get { }` style property. BUT the most `wpf` way to do it would be a converter as I've done above - the converter has the bonus that it doesn't dirty your `Person` class with a property you'll just use for displaying purposes...